# How to recognize from which stream, the event was emitted in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, stream

I have stream from Db and I'm spitting it to many HTTP servers via HTTP (request). 
To split this stream I use `passThrough`
Everything works well, but when the event is called I don't know which stream emit it.
Is any solution to identify that stream?. 
I'm using error, end, data, and response events. 
In response I have information about host but most important is to identify it in error eventListener.

```
const stream = await getDataStream(id);
const passThrough = new PassThrough();
stream.pipe(objectToString).pipe(passThrough);

for (let host of hostsList) {
  startedRequestsCount++;
  host.stream
    .on('error', errorHandler)
    .on('data', dataHandler)
    .on('response', responseHandler)
    .on('end', resolveAfterAllRequests);
  passThrough.pipe(host.stream);
}
```

I have a lot of doubts about this solution but for now, it's working.
Problem is when I receive an error and want to know which host was failed.

**Bonus question**:

If I'm streaming via HTTP can I handle back pressure issue?

Comment: What is `element` ?

Comment: @JonasWilms it was a typo. This is host and host is an object which contains stream (request)).

Comment: Note that piping one stream to many might cause backpressuring problems.

Comment: @JonasWilms Yes, I know, hence my bonus question ;)

Comment: ... oops. Somehow skipped that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When defining the handlers use currying to take an additional stream parameter:

```
  const errorHandler = stream => error => {
   console.log(stream, error);
 };
```

Then cook the curry:

```
 host.stream
  .on('error', errorHandler(host.stream));
```

for sure you can pass in multiple arguments with that pattern.

Comment: Thanks, this is that what I needed.